# how can orderBy column in eloquent laravel add with $appends

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how can i orderyby desc or asc column.add with $appends (infact this column not exist)

```
protected $appends = ['time_online','user_is'];
public function getTimeOnlineAttribute(){
    if (!empty($this->created_at) && !empty($this->expired_at)) {
        return $this->created_at->diffInMinutes($this->expired_at);
}}
```

in query:

```
$search=$request->search;  
$columnName=$request->column_name;
$result=Model::WhereSearch($search)->orderBy($columnName,$dir)->paginate($request->length);
return response()->json(['data'=>$visitors]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orderByRaw()`

```
Model::whereSearch($search)
    ->orderByRaw('created_at - expired_at DESC')
    ->paginate($request->length);
```